# Bootbox: how to avoid recursive calls?

Tags: javascript, bootbox

I have the following code:

```
$('boddy').click(function(e) {
   bootbox.alert("clicked!");
});
```

When a page is clicked, I see a popup window with "clicked" displayed. However, if I click the OK button to close it, the popup shows up again and never ends.

Interestingly, I tried the following code:

```
$('boddy').click(function(e) {
   alert("clicked!");
});
```

After I click the OK button in the popup, it never shows up again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap modals (and therefore Bootbox modals) are simply `<div>` elements with higher z-indexes than the rest of the page content. They're still contained with the body of the page, so when you click on any element in the modal, it propagates through every parent element of the modal. Since the body tag is the top-level parent, clicking a button in the modal ultimately also clicks the body element.

Comment: Tieson, any twist I can do to achieve the same effect as  from the native alert()? Thanks!

Comment: @curious1 Possibly adding a conditional around the bootbox call, and checking to see if the triggering element has something with the "modal" class as a parent; if it does, stop the event propagation and/or don't call bootbox again.